# “Application not installed on phone ” Error for Wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I made a live wallpaper which was working fine until I did the following **changes**:

1. added admob integration.
2. Changed package name
3. changed sdk version from 2.1 to 4.1.2

**Problem :** Whenever I click on Settings button I get error application not installed on phone, even if the application is installed and live wallpaper is set.I'm unable to open setting screen now after doing the above changes.

**Note:** I'm using unsigned apk (simpling running project through eclipse)

**Android Manifiest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.AppLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.Gallery_Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.SettingActivity"
            android:exported="true" >
        </activity>

        <!-- start-code for admob banner -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <!-- end-code for admob banner -->

        <receiver android:name="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.FlareLiveWallpaper"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/flare_lwp" />
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have **referred** the following links but no luck on finding the solution:

["Application not installed" for Live Wallpaper, on some phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218252/application-not-installed-for-live-wallpaper-on-some-phones)

[Android error: Application is not installed on your phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162196/android-error-application-is-not-installed-on-your-phone)

[Application not Installed' Error on Android 2.3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925696/application-not-installed-error-on-android-2-3-4?rq=1)

[Android application not installed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814465/android-application-not-installed-error)

**EDIT**

**flare_lwp.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wallpaper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:settingsActivity="com.fireworks.happylivewallpaper.SettingActivity"
        android:thumbnail="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Post your `flare_lwp` XML

Comment: @Apoorv I have added flare_lwp .Now I realised that the refractor doest not change the package name in xmls! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
android:settingsActivity="com.fireworks.happylivewallpaper.SettingActivity"
```

to

```
android:settingsActivity="com.fireworks.nightskylivewallpaper.SettingActivity"
```

in your `flare_lwp` XML file. Your package name hasn't been changed there.